# How to map objects in state to a dynamic list in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As of my current knowledge now, I know that you can map an array from state to HTML elements and can make an array of elements that can repeat itself over and over again. However, is that any way for me to do the same but to map out items into a list so I can dynamically populate my dictionary?

So what I want is to have this:

```
this.setState({         
    series: [
    {
        name: 'Bob',
        data: [
        {
            x: 'Block 396 HDB Tampines',
            y: [
            new Date('2019-03-05').getTime(),
            new Date('2019-03-08').getTime()
            ]
        },
        {
            x: 'Eastpoint Mall',
            y: [
            new Date('2019-03-02').getTime(),
            new Date('2019-03-05').getTime()
            ]
        },
        {
            x: 'Bata',
            y: [
            new Date('2019-03-05').getTime(),
            new Date('2019-03-07').getTime()
            ]
        },
        {
            x: 'Barracuda Tech',
            y: [
            new Date('2019-03-03').getTime(),
            new Date('2019-03-09').getTime()
            ]
        },
        {
            x: 'Aromas of India',
            y: [
            new Date('2019-03-08').getTime(),
            new Date('2019-03-11').getTime()
            ]
        },
        {
            x: '517 Food court',
            y: [
            new Date('2019-03-11').getTime(),
            new Date('2019-03-16').getTime()
            ]
        },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [
        {
            x: 'Aljunied Industrial Estate',
            y: [
            new Date('2019-03-02').getTime(),
            new Date('2019-03-05').getTime()
            ]
        },
        {
            x: 'Bata',
            y: [
            new Date('2019-03-06').getTime(),
            new Date('2019-03-16').getTime()
            ]
        },
        {
            x: 'YinJi Singapore',
            y: [
            new Date('2019-03-03').getTime(),
            new Date('2019-03-07').getTime()
            ]
        },
        {
            x: 'Aromas of India',
            y: [
            new Date('2019-03-20').getTime(),
            new Date('2019-03-22').getTime()
            ]
        },
        {
            x: 'Djitsun Mall',
            y: [
            new Date('2019-03-10').getTime(),
            new Date('2019-03-16').getTime()
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    ],
})
```

Above is what I want to have as my final outcome

Below is the code that I have been trying but it seems impossible

```
this.setState({
            series: [
                ...this.state.suspectCases.map(suspect => {
                    return{
                        name: suspect.firstName + " " + suspect.lastName,
                        data:[
                            {
                                x: 'Block 396 HDB Tampines',
                                y: [
                                new Date('2019-03-05').getTime(),
                                new Date('2019-03-08').getTime()
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                x: 'Eastpoint Mall',
                                y: [
                                new Date('2019-03-02').getTime(),
                                new Date('2019-03-05').getTime()
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                x: 'Bata',
                                y: [
                                new Date('2019-03-05').getTime(),
                                new Date('2019-03-07').getTime()
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                x: 'Barracuda Tech',
                                y: [
                                new Date('2019-03-03').getTime(),
                                new Date('2019-03-09').getTime()
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                x: 'Aromas of India',
                                y: [
                                new Date('2019-03-08').getTime(),
                                new Date('2019-03-11').getTime()
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                x: '517 Food court',
                                y: [
                                new Date('2019-03-11').getTime(),
                                new Date('2019-03-16').getTime()
                                ]
                            },
                        ]
                    }
                    
                })            
            ]
        })
```

Are there any ways to do this? Or is this impossible and requires other backends to do it?
P.S.: I have not done anything for the data as I was still trying to see if the name works first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to populate an array before set the state like

```
let series = []
this.state.suspectCases.foreach(suspect => {
    series.push(
        {
            name: suspect.firstName + " " + suspect.lastName,
            data:[
                {
                    x: 'Block 396 HDB Tampines',
                    y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-05').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-08').getTime()
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Eastpoint Mall',
                    y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-02').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-05').getTime()
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Bata',
                    y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-05').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-07').getTime()
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Barracuda Tech',
                    y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-03').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-09').getTime()
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Aromas of India',
                    y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-08').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-11').getTime()
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: '517 Food court',
                    y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-11').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-16').getTime()
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    )
}) 

this.setState({series})
```

OR

```
let series = this.state.suspectCases.map(suspect => {
    return(
        {
            name: suspect.firstName + " " + suspect.lastName,
            data:[
                {
                    x: 'Block 396 HDB Tampines',
                    y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-05').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-08').getTime()
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Eastpoint Mall',
                    y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-02').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-05').getTime()
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Bata',
                    y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-05').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-07').getTime()
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Barracuda Tech',
                    y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-03').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-09').getTime()
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: 'Aromas of India',
                    y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-08').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-11').getTime()
                    ]
                },
                {
                    x: '517 Food court',
                    y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-11').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-16').getTime()
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    )
}) 

this.setState({series})
```

Comment: You are now using the map function as a forEach. Instead of `series.push` just return the object.

Comment: My bad, i wanted to use a foreach

Comment: Still, you are using a `forEeach` for a operation that more suitable to a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Same... I added it anyway

Comment: Where are you setting your state ? If you do it in componentDidUpdate or componentWillUpdate , each render make a new render and you are in an infinite loop. Place it in componentDidMount or in a method.